# Using aggregate function for computation in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2014

This is the `Employee` table schema:

[image]

This is the `Works_on` schema:

[image]

Using these two tables, I am executing this query:

[image]

The error shows up when I execute the query:

[image]

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

The `Group By` clause should be: **`Group By E.Ssn, E.FName`**

Comment: Ah, sorry.  The _Group By_ should be:  **`Group By W.Essn, E.Fname`**